# How to center Icon in navbar with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to create navbar with a hamburger on the left and icon centered. How can I do this with responsively?

1. I tried to use mx-auto (margin-left margin-right: auto) but since I have a inline block on the left, the centered icon is pushed to the left.
2. I have also tried making the navbar d-flex and add justify-content-center but it just did nothing...

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="pos-f-t">
  <nav id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-expand-sm fixed-top navbar-dark bg-dark d-flex flex-row">
    <button class="navbar-toggler d-flex justify-content-start" type="button">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/20" alt="apple icon" class="d-flex justify-content-center mx-auto" id="icon">

  </nav>
</div>
```

Expected result:
- Hamburger stays left, but apple icon stay center.

Actual result:
- apple icon pushed slightly right by hamburger,
- or nothing changed at all, just sitting at the right side.

Comment: Can you please post both HTML and CSS code, which can be run to check the issue OR create a JSfiddle / Codepen.

Comment: Do you want it to be in the center of the whole navbar, instead of the part of navbar that is left after the hamburger icon?

Answer (score 1):

This works perfectly with your above code. Check the below screenshot.

[image]

Make sure you have added the bootstrap4 css file

Comment: I think the OP wants it to be in the center of the whole navbar, instead of the part of  navbar that is left after the hamburger icon

Comment: @NanditaSharma But this is not what is mentioned above

Comment: I had a doubt and thats why I have asked the OP about the same.

Answer (score 1):

Lewis, Your code is working fine. I just added bootstrap4 CSS file. Below is my code.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<div class="pos-f-t">
        <nav
          id="navbar"
          class="navbar navbar-expand-sm fixed-top navbar-dark bg-dark d-flex flex-row"
        >
          <button class="navbar-toggler d-flex justify-content-start" type="button">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <img
            src="http://www.newdesignfile.com/postpic/2012/09/small-apple-logo_154074.jpg"
            alt="apple icon"
            class="d-flex justify-content-center mx-auto"
            id="icon"
            width="50px"
          />
        </nav>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you can do here is that add a right padding equal to the width of the navbar toggle button (width = 56px) to navbar. It already has a right padding of 16px. So, our total padding should be 16px + 56px = 72px.

This will align the image exactly in the center of the navbar.

```css
.navbar-fix {
  padding-right: 72px !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="pos-f-t">
  <nav id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-expand-sm fixed-top navbar-dark bg-dark d-flex flex-row navbar-fix">
    <button class="navbar-toggler d-flex justify-content-start" type="button">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/20" alt="apple icon" class="d-flex justify-content-center mx-auto" id="icon">

  </nav>
</div>
```